# Developing for the Nokia 3120?

Tags: java-me, nokia, mobile-phones, series-40

I want to develop an application for [Nokia 3120](http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/3120). It is said that the developer platform is "Series 40 Developer Platform 1.0" but from the "Series 40 Platform SDKs" page, no SDK Series 40 for Platform 1.0 is available, I can just see Series 40, Developer Platform 2.0 and so on.

Can I develop an application that will run on Nokia 3120 using the Series 40, Developer Platform 2.0 or 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your best, if not only, option is Java ME MIDP. You can program your [MIDlets](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDlet&ei=hDH0Tee-NcvCtAbyxK28Bg&usg=AFQjCNEx8uY54yZacrYb2kzWqmonBJ1F0Q) with later versions of the Series 40 SDK; just remember not to use any APIs that are not available on the Nokia 3120. The APIs section of the document you linked to lists only the basic MIDP/CLDC/Nokia UI APIs:

> JSR 30 Connected, Limited Device Configuration (CLDC) 1.0
>
> JSR 37 MIDP 1.0
>
> Nokia UI API